# How to count the duplicate column values in sql

Tags: sql, count, sum, distinct

I have values of table 'testsql1' as follows:

```
(myid (int), col1 (nvarchar), col2 (binary)) 
VALUES (10, 'Prod', 0), (10, 'Test', 0), (10, 'Review', 1),
       (11,'Prod', 0), (11, Review, 1)
```

I have to select the data as follows

```
(myid, col1, col3) 
VALUES (10, Review, 3), (11, Review, 2)
```

Basically I want only the 'Review' data and a calculated col3 which should tell the count of duplicate 'myid' for all 'Review' as col1. Condition for col2 is that it is binary and always contains value 1 when col1 is 'Review'

I have tried the following

```
select myid, col1, count(myid) as col3
from testsql1
where col1 = 'Review'
group by myid, col1;
```

but it just gives me value of col3 as 1 for both myids (10 and 11)

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. As I see it, the result is correct, both ID's have 1 review record

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use like this...

```
select myid, 'Review' as col1, count(myid) as col3
from testsql1
group by myid;
```

Comment: Why would you expect a different result with this query?

Comment: Did you notice @lad2025's answer?

Comment: @HoneyBadger because when you group by the col1, you'll filter only the columns that have "Review" on it. That's why your result is bringing you only 1 at col3

Comment: @HoneyBadger he posted almost at the same time than me

Comment: "he posted almost at the same time than me",  3 minutes before with demo. Seems legit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
select myid, 'Review' AS col1, count(myid) as col3
from testsql1
group by myid;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424063)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦════════╦══════╗
║ myid ║  col1  ║ col3 ║
╠══════╬════════╬══════╣
║   10 ║ Review ║    3 ║
║   11 ║ Review ║    2 ║
╚══════╩════════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select distinct a.myid,'Review' as col1,a.col3
From (select myid, count(myid) as col3
from testsql1
group by myid) a,testsql1 b
where col1 = 'Review' and a.myid = b.myid
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

select col1, count(myid) as col3
from testsql1
where col1='Review'
group by col1;